# How to sum nested values from a JSON array based on conditions

Tags: postgresql, json, aggregate

I have a table with 3 columns in Postgres 14.2: `name`, `name_adds`, `aditional`.

And these rules:

1. `name` and `name_adds` can be filled with the same value or not. Example:
   name (john) and name_adds (doe) or both value is (john)
2. column `additional` has one of two formats:

   format 1:

   `{"default":[{"value_1": 100, "value_2": 0.1},{"value_1": 200, "value_2": 0.2}],  "non_default":[{"value_1": 200, "value_2": 0.1}, {"value_1": 400, "value_2": 0.1}]}`

   format 2:

   `[{"value_1": 10,"value_2": 11},{"value_1": 1,"value_2": 19}`
3. If (name = name_adds)  sum default -> value_1
4. If (name != name_adds) sum non_default -> value_1

How can I sum format 1 or 2 from point *2.* based on the rules in point *3.* and *4.*?

Example table:

```
name    name_adds   additional
---------------------------------------------------------------
john    john      {"default":[{"value_1": 100, "value_2": 0.1}, 
                  {"value_1": 200, "value_2": 0.2}],"non_default": 
                  [{"value_1": 200, "value_2": 0.1}, {"value_1": 400, 
                   "value_2": 0.1}]}

john     doe     {"default":[{"value_1": 100, "value_2": 0.1}, 
                  {"value_1": 200, "value_2": 0.2}],"non_default": 
                  [{"value_1": 200, "value_2": 0.1}, {"value_1": 400, 
                   "value_2": 0.1}]}

downy    downy    [{"value_1": 10, "value_2": 11},{"value_1": 1,"value_2": 19}]

downy    dan      [{"value_1": 10, "value_2": 11},{"value_1": 1,"value_2": 19}]
```

Expected result:

```
name    name_adds   sum_result
---------------------------------------------------------------
john    john        300

john     doe        600

downy    downy      11

downy    dan        11
```

I tried a query in this [online demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=ff64419f97cf43cb012c8c5f08ca5c5e), but didn't manage to get the expected result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT a.name, a.name_adds, sub.*
FROM   test_json a
CROSS  JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT sum((obj ->> 'value_1')::int) AS sum_result  -- or numeric?
   FROM   json_array_elements(COALESCE(CASE WHEN name = name_adds
                                            THEN additional::json -> 'default'
                                            ELSE additional::json -> 'non_default' END
                                     , additional::json)) obj
   ) sub;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=c17543f609dc6e7c9869f5f937b842d0)*

This relies on `additional::json -> 'default'` (or `'non_default'`, respectively) being NULL in case of "format 2", in which case we take `additional::json` directly for "format 1" using `COALESCE`.
Then unnest with [`json_array_elements()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE), and sum extracted `value_1`.

The column `additional` should be type `json` (or `jsonb`) to begin with.

Chances are, you would be much better off with a normalized relational design *replacing* that highly regular JSON column completely.

Comment: cool it's work, you are right about additional type, I will change it.
Thanks a lot